# avr-gcc How to put strings in progmem?

Tags: avr, avr-gcc, progmem

I have question how to put strings in progmem? Here is sample program.

```
void ParAdd(uint8_t type, const char *ParName){
    #do something meaningful here
}

int main (void){
    ParAdd(11,  "Name1");
    ParAdd(22,  "Name2");
    ParAdd(30,  "Name3");
}
```

Is there a way to declare string parameter in function call as PROGMEM? I know for 'clasic' way like:

```
char string_1[] PROGMEM = "String 1";
char string_2[] PROGMEM = "String 2";
```

..but in my case I prefer to be in single line if possible. The example program is meninglles but in real case there are many parameters and many "ParAdd" calls. But can't find solution to use something like:

```
ParAdd(11,  (PROGMEM) "Name1");
```

Someone know solution for that? Something like F() macro in arduino?

Answer (score 3):

...fell stupid as solution is so easy.

```
ParAdd(11,  PSTR("Name1"));
```

is the solution.